# Enable CORS while an XMLHttpRequest error occurs in flutter web

Tags: dart, xmlhttprequest, flutter-web

when I will add data to the database using the function, and on the server I have added `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` so that it is not blocked by CORS, but still error when I looked in the browser console tools tab console

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://int.goo.id/api/pg/sso.register' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

how to deactivate CORS??

Comment: I think you can't. You have to configure your server to add CORS header Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <host>:<port>

Comment: I have added it on the server but only 2 functions to the database are blocked by cors namely the function to insert data

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60191683/xmlhttprequest-error-in-flutter-web-enabling-cors-aws-api-gateway/65858677#65858677

Answer (score 3):

For enabling cors on my server and to resolve **XMLHttpRequest error in flutter web**

I am using this in my `.htaccess` file for **allowing access to certain domains only**

```
 <ifModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(localhost:25120|domain.com|domain2.com)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
 </ifModule>
```

Comment: where to add .htaccess file like near to pubspec.yml ? or where
Please help me

Comment: `.htaccess` file will be stored on your server index directory not on your mobile app's directory

Comment: can you be more clear as to where the `.htaccess` file is?

Comment: @icyNerd Create a  .htaccress  file on your server where you published the built web files. (Next to the main.dart.js, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who is using node.js server, enable cors support in your server side code.

1. npm i cors express
2. In index.js or server.js -

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
var cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());
```

This should fix cors issue with flutter web

Comment: great its working for me

Answer (score 0):

if you have experienced something like that, and the server has added `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` but is still blocked by CORS, try checking the function (if you use the function to CRUD with postrgresql) because my problem is solved when I fix the function

Answer (score 0):

Disabling CORS policy on Chrome is a temporary solution. It's just frustrating that you have to manually call it before starting Chrome every. single. time.
[Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)

Comment: is there is any alternate solution for this, still facing the same issue ???

Answer (score 0):

Vicky Salunkhe described in his answer one option with .htaccess very well. I found that and an alternative if you try to read from a server where you are running a php script yourself [here](https://secure.plusplushosting.net/knowledgebase/1517/How-to-enable-CORS-in-your-hosting-account.html). If you want to read some data from a MySQL database and return it as json with the right CORS setting, you could try this:

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');


$host_name = '...';
$database = '...';
$user_name = '...';
$password = '...';

$link = new mysqli($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);
if ($link->connect_error) {    
    die('<p>Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . $link->connect_error .
     '</p>');
}
$link->set_charset('utf8mb4');

$sql = "...";
$result = $link->query($sql);
$result = $link->query($sql);
$data = $link->query($sql)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($data);
```