# How to configure CORS using Flutter Web and CanvasKit renderer?

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter-web, firebase-hosting

### Problem

I have a Flutter Web project hosted on Firebase Hosting rendered with CanvasKit and I can't make it load external images hosted in a Xano CDN or load GooglePlaces API results (autocompiling).
I read many other solutions (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65630743/how-to-solve-flutter-web-api-cors-error-only-with-dart-code) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60309210/flutter-web-dart-cors-error-with-firebase-hosting) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65653801/flutter-web-cant-load-network-image-from-another-domain)) but none works. I also [configured CORS on Google Cloud](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#cors_configuration).

### My files

This is my `firebase.json` file:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build/web",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "*",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
            "value": "*"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In index.html I have appended the following script, right before the `</body>` tag:

```
<!-- Firebase -->
<script type="module">
  // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
  import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.10/firebase-app.js";
  import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.10/firebase-analytics.js";
  // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
  // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: *mykey*,
    authDomain: "hearth-148b0.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "hearth-148b0",
    storageBucket: "hearth-148b0.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: *id*,
    appId: *myappid*,
    measurementId: *id*
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
</script>
```

I tried to include the header in the CachedNetworkImage:

```
return CachedNetworkImage(
    httpHeaders: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"},
    imageUrl: imageUrl,
    fit: fit,
    width: width,
    height: height,
    progressIndicatorBuilder: (context, url, downloadProgress) =>
        LoadingPlaceholder(width: width),
    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => SizedBox(width: width),
  );
```

And I tried to include the headers in GooglePlace initializer:

```
 final GooglePlace googlePlace = GooglePlace(
    kTokenGMaps,
    headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"},
  );
```

### The errors

These are the type of errors I get from the browser console:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

or

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://storage.googleapis.com/xatr-ly1x-gkt1.n7.xano.io/vault/xhL5_hu1/fMPW0YCx/C01_Ng../9de15d31/Monumento_ai_caduti_in_Corso_Europa.jpg'
> (redirected from
> 'https://xatr-ly1x-gkt1.n7.xano.io/vault/xhL5_hu1/fMPW0YCx/C01_Ng../Monumento_ai_caduti_in_Corso_Europa.jpg?tpl=big:box')
> from origin 'https://hearth-148b0.web.app' has been blocked by CORS
> policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
> requested resource.

### Deploy

These are the commands I use to deploy on firebase, from android studio:

```
flutter build web
firebase deploy
```

### Alternative

I also tried to use another host with FTP and setting the .htaccess file to:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
```

but no success.

Comment: The ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT error is the root error that needs to be fixed; the CORS error is a side effect; if the cause of the ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT error is fixed, the CORS problem will probably go away too. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT+%5Bfirebase%5D

Comment: How did you fix it?

Comment: I changed the server and it got fixed by itself in a day or so. I suspect it was a server cache problem but I wouldn't bet on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem by adjusting the CORS settings on the server side. Initially, I thought it was a client problem, but it turned out to be caused by a misconfiguration on the server.

In my case, I was using Firebase Storage, and I had to create a cors.json file on my computer to enable CORS. Here's what my configuration looked like:

```
[
  {
    "origin": ["*"],
    "method": ["GET"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

To break this down:

- `"origin": ["*"]` allows requests from any origin to access the resource. You can specify a specific domain or a list of domains to restrict the origins that are allowed to access the resource.
- `"method": ["GET"]` allows only GET requests to access the resource. You can include other HTTP methods like POST, PUT, DELETE, etc. to restrict the methods that are allowed to access the resource.
- `"maxAgeSeconds": 3600` caches the CORS configuration in the browser for 1 hour (3600 seconds). Subsequent requests from the same origin and method will not require a CORS check during the cache duration.

After creating the cors.json file, and after [installing `gsutil`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install), execute this command in your terminal:

```
gsutil cors set cors.json gs://<bucket>.appspot.com
```

Make sure to replace `<bucket>` with the name of your storage bucket.

By following these steps, I was able to fix my CORS issue and enable access to my resources.